# Is $\{\frac 1n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ countable?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the set $\{\frac 1n :n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ countable?

This was part of the Exercises in a book on Real Analysis. The answer given is that this set is uncountable.

**My work:**

I'm just starting on Real Analysis and , to my knowledge, this set is countable, since we can map every element of this set to natural numbers as
\begin{eqnarray}1&\to&1\\
2&\to&\frac12\\
3&\to&\frac13
\end{eqnarray}
and so on.

So, is there a mistake in the book?

Comment: It is countable.

Comment: since it's included in $\mathbb Q$....

Comment: I got it. Thanks!

Comment: by the way, your application for $\mathbb N\to\{1/n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ is indeed a bijection.

Comment: @Surb $[0,1]-\{\frac 1n :n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is uncountable, since [0,1] is uncountable, isn't it?

Comment: @neo, yes, the complementary set $[0,1]\setminus\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb N\right\}$ *is* uncountable.

Comment: The argument is not correct, but indeed it's uncountable... @neo

Comment: What is the text that you're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...To my knowledge, this set is countable, since we can map every element of this set to natural numbers as
> \begin{eqnarray}1&\to&1\\
> 2&\to&\frac12\\
> 3&\to&\frac13
> \end{eqnarray}
> and so on.

This is sort of the correct reasoning for why the set is countable.

There are two common definitions of "countable".

One common definition of "Set $X$ is *countable*" is that: "there exists an *[injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function)* $f:X\to\mathbb{N}.$"

The other definition of "Set $X$ is *countable*" which is that: "there exists a [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) $f:X\to\mathbb{N}.$"

The distinction between the two definitions is that the first definition allows for finite sets to be called "countable", whereas the second definition does not. [Note that countably infinite sets satisfy both definitions.]

Let's adopt the second definition. If you want to be more rigorous, you will have to *either* show that the map

$$ f:\mathbb{N}\to \left\{ \frac{1}{n}: n\in\mathbb{N} \right\}; \qquad f(n)=\frac{1}{n}$$

is bijective, or equivalently - because "is bijective" is an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) - that the map

$$ g: \left\{ \frac{1}{n}: n\in\mathbb{N} \right\} \to \mathbb{N}; \qquad  g(n)=\frac{1}{n} $$

is bijective.

Note that we cannot *assume* that either function has an inverse, since in order for a function to have an inverse, it must first be true that the function is a bijection, which is what we are trying to prove.

Anyway, the moral of the story is, if you're stuck in maths, then going back to the definitions is usually not a bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. As a subset of a countable set is countable, and rationals are (Countability of Rational Numbers), the set $\{\frac 1n :n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is countable.
Another way to see it is that for all $n$, $n+1$ exists. If you add $\frac 1n + \frac{2n+1}{n^2 +n}$ you get $\frac {1}{n+1}$, so it always exists. You can use proof by induction or reductio ad absurdum.

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The former approach is definitely a way to show countability, but the latter is questionable. Better than both is to use the bijection $f:\Bbb N\to\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb N\right\}$ given by $f(n)=\frac1n,$ as suggested by the OP.